# Cannot find DNX runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta-001598

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

For Win7 Machine I installed latest version of .net core from https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows

Here are my dotnetcore and dnvm versions

[image: donetcore and dnvm versions]

I also installed vs 2015 update 3. When I try to build my project I am getting following error:

> Cannot find DNX runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta-001598

Seems like VS 2015 tries to use same version of dnx of sdk version (1.0.0-beta-001598)

When I check packages at nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/dnx-clr-win-x86/) I cannot find version of 1.0.0-beta-001598.

How can I fix this issue?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are trying to use the latest version?

If that is the case you can just remove the entire "sdk" section from your global.json and it will automatically choose the latest version.

Source:

https://docs.asp.net/en/1.0.0-rc1/conceptual-overview/understanding-aspnet5-apps.html#the-global-json-file

Comment: I tried this. Now I am getting error of: " The .NET Core SDK is not installed or cannot be found under the path C:\Program Files\dotnet\bin" But it is there :(

Comment: I would reinstall it from the directions on https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows.  
One of the prerequisites is uninstalling previous versions of coreclr/dotnet core.

Comment: Did this as well, removed all prev SDKs and installed latest one, no luck. acts like SDK never installed. If I put sdk section back, again tries to find dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta-001598. Is there any way to specify what dnx version to use? I did same think on win10 machine yesterday, and all worked fine. Not sure what is the issue with win7 machine.

Comment: dnx and dnvm are for beta and rc1.  They do not work with RC2 and RTM.  The newest versions use dotnet.  Unfortunately I don't have a windows 7 machine to test on :(.  My windows 10 experience is similar to yours.  It just worked.

Comment: I will take this as an answer. Combination of "removing sdk section" and  "Uninstall Microsoft .NET CLI for Windows from control panel if it exists." fixed the issue. Thanks for redirection. This answer helped me as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37308921/929902
I was only removing SDK installations did not notice CLI had to be uninstalled as well.